# Install Entity Framework 6.1.2 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I have an old web project with EF 4.0. Trying upgrade to new version.

I cleared the `packages` folder. I deleted the `packages.config` file.

Then I opened the Package Manager Console, typed `install-package -id EntityFramework` and pressed enter.

```
PM> install-package -id EntityFramework
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.1.2'.
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320539. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.2'.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.1.2' to ProjectName.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package -id EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Trying to uninstall:

```
PM> uninstall-package EntityFramework
Removing 'EntityFramework 6.1.2' from ProjectName.
uninstall-package : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:1 char:1
+ uninstall-package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UninstallPackageCommand
```

Trying to install one more time:

```
PM> install-package EntityFramework
'EntityFramework 6.1.2' already installed.
ProjectName already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 6.1.2'.
```

Then trying add new model and can't choose EF 6.0

[image]

How can I start working with EF 6.0?

Comment: Deleting the packages folder and then deleting the packages.config file is not a good way to remove packages. You should right click on the project references and then go to "manage nuget packages". From there you should uncheck whatever packages you want to remove, and then nuget will do the rest. What is probably happening now is that your project is still referencing the old EF dll, even though you have deleted the package and the .config file. Try to manually remove the EF dependency from the project. Please keep in mind that you should probably have just updated EF to the latest version.

Comment: First thing what i made was "manage nuget package", but this just throw me "Input string was not in a correct format".
Then i start clear dependency manually.
What else i should clear?

Comment: I've had lots of small bugs with the nuget extension in Visual Studio giving me these sorts of random messages, and usually restarting VS solves all of them. Please check if your project still references an old EF dll and remove that. Also, when closing VS, sometimes deleting the .suo file that resides in the same folder as your solution is a good ideia. The suo is a binary cache of sorts that stores your environment state for that solution (like opened tabs, breakpoints, which projects are loaded or unloaded, etc). Make sure to delete it before reopening VS.

Comment: Ah, and I forgot to add this, but the .suo file is hidden, so if it does not show in your explorer please go to folder options and enable showing hidden files first.

Comment: This partly solved my problem. Now i can add EF 4 model (during attempt change version both 4 and 6 was broken). But still can't use EF 6. If i remove reference on `System.Data.Entity` then i can install EF 6 and add EF 6 model, but it still not compile with error `The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'`

Comment: Now i try to do it again. I updated nuget to last version, created a new project (simple console application), in new solution. Then opened Pacage Manager Console, typed `Install-Package EntityFramework` and press Enter. Error still here. It was in step `Adding 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to ProjectName`. When i do second attempt where is no error `'EntityFramework 6.1.3' already installed.
ProjectName already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 6.1.3'`, but after add the model i had compiler error `The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'`.

Comment: I have to say I have no idea what is happening then. If the problem persist even in a clean solution this must be some general issue with your installation. Can you perhaps test the same steps on another computer? Maybe you'll have to share a sample solution that shows the problem so that we can take a look. I've never seen a case where starting from scratch like you did still generated an error.